# Not modifying the calling instance

Tags: python, object

I'm trying to make a scalar product of a vector `v1.scalar_product(3)` but noticed that the instance is getting changed too.

```py
    class Vector(object):
        def __init__(self, data = None):
            if data is None:
                self._vector = []
            else:
                self._vector = data[:]

        def __str__(self):
            if self._vector == []:
                return '<>'
            else:
                return ('<'+ str(float(self._vector[0])) + ', ' + str(float(self._vector[1])) + ', ' + str(float(self._vector[2])) + '>')

        def dim(self):
            if self._vector == None:
                return 0
            else:
                return len(self._vector)

        def get(self, index):
            if index > self.dim():
                raise IndexError
            else:
                return float(self._vector[index])

        def set(self, index, value):
            if index > self.dim():
                raise IndexError
            else:
                self._vector[index] = value

        def scalar_product(self, scalar):
            v3 = self
            for i in range(self.dim()):
                v3.set(i, self.get(i) * scalar)
            return v3._vector

    v1 = Vector([1, 2, 3])
    v2 = v1.scalar_product(3)
```

`v2` correctly returns `[3.0, 6.0, 9.0]` but `v1` should remain unchanged `[1, 2, 3]` but currently gets changed to `<3.0, 6.0, 9.0>`  Why?

Answer (score 1):

While doing `scalar_product`, you're modifying your `v1` instance (because of `v3 = self`). If you would like to return a new vector instead of modifying the current one, create a new instance of `v3` using deep copy or new Vector.

```py
    import copy
    def scalar_product(self, scalar):
        # using deep copy
        v3 = copy.deepcopy(self)
        # or using new Vector object and list builtin copy
        v3 = Vector(data=self._vector.copy())
        for i in range(self.dim()):
            v3.set(i, self.get(i) * scalar)
        return v3._vector
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not directly modifying v1, but you are doing a `v3=self`

Then when you will modify v3, it will modify self, so it will modify v1.
Instead of doing `v3 = self` you should prefer `v3 = copy.deepcopy(v3)` after importing the copy module.

Then print v1 and v2 :

```py
v1 = <1.0, 2.0, 3.0>
v2 = [3.0, 6.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v3 = self`, you should create a new `Vector` based on the data of `self` and modify that:

```
def scalar_product(self, scalar):
    v3 = Vector(self._vector)
    for i in range(self.dim()):
        v3.set(i, self.get(i) * scalar)
    return v3._vector
```

But since you are just returning the inner list, not a new vector (or should it be `return v3`?), you could just as well use a list comprehension:

```
def scalar_product(self, scalar):
    return [self.get(i) * scalar for i in range(self.dim())]
```